# javascript flashing effect after you answer a question, or when you cannot vote down and close the warning

Tags: javascript

does anybody know any resources that I can refer to?

Comment: To be specific: stackoverflow does use JQuery. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to the [JQuery FadeOut effect](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback) (since [Stackoverflow uses JQuery](http://ttp://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/))

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow uses the JQuery library, and it uses the [fadeOut effect](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut#speedcallback) for what you are describing.

I have never used JQuery, but I have used the [scriptaculous](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis) library to do this same thing in the past.

The [Effect.highlight](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/effect-highlight) effect is probably the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can easlily find this and lots of other effects in various javascript libraries. 
I personally like [JQuery](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/real-world/effects/)